# how to run node shelljs in sync mode and get stdout and stderr

Tags: node.js, shelljs

Within a nodejs script I have the following code which makes the call synchronously and returns the stdout from the shell script I am calling:

```
var sh = require('shelljs');

... some code
var output = sh.exec('./someshellscript.sh', {silent:true}).stdout;
console.log(output);
... some more code (that shouldnt run until the script is complete)
```

I can also run the following script which will instead return the stderr:

```
var sh = require('shelljs');

... some code
var output = sh.exec('./someshellscript.sh', {silent:true}).stderr;
console.log(output);
... some more code (that shouldnt run until the script is complete)
```

However I want to receive both stdout and stderr in a sync call. Its probably something pretty obvious I am missing herebut I cant work it out.

I think you used to be able run the following command in previous versions but this just returns undefined now:

```
var sh = require('shelljs');

... some code
var output = sh.exec('./someshellscript.sh', {silent:true}).output;
console.log(output);
... some more code (that shouldnt run until the script is complete)
```

Relevant software versions are:

- Ubuntu: 14.04.3 LTS
- node: 4.4.4
- npm: 2.15.1
- shelljs: 0.7.0

Any help appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From the [README for the method `exec(command [, options] [, callback])`](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs#execcommand--options--callback)

> Executes the given command synchronously, unless otherwise specified. [...], returns an object of the form { code:..., stdout:... , stderr:... }).

Therefore

```
const { stdout, stderr, code } = sh.exec('./someshellscript.sh', { silent: true })
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the prompt answer. Perfect :)

Comment: show a code:127   /bin/sh: 1: ./nginx_betaproduct.sh: not found