# Raspberry Pi 4 To A Remote MySql: Stderr : /bin/sh: 1: mysql: not found

Tags: javascript, mysql, shell, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

In continuation to my previous question here (Fully details: [connect Raspberry Pi 4 to a remote MySql database located on a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74994968/connect-raspberry-pi-4-to-a-remote-mysql-database-located-on-a-server)), I have been digging to find out what causing the error and why my `Raspberry Pi 4` fails to connect to a remote `MySql` database through `JavaScript` but, it makes a perfect connection through `Python` script.

I executed the following `shelljs.exec()` command to know the cause (inspired from: [how to run node shelljs in sync mode and get stdout and stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37263863/how-to-run-node-shelljs-in-sync-mode-and-get-stdout-and-stderr)) and I got the following output. I need help to know what this error mean and I need to do fix it.
My code and output:

```
>> var shell = require('shelljs');
>> const { stdout, stderr, code } = shell.exec(command, { silent: true })
>> console.log("Stdout: "+stdout+", Stderr: "+stderr+", Code: "+code)
# Output is 
>> Stdout: , Stderr: /bin/sh: 1: mysql: not found, Code: 127
```

My understanding from above is, there is no output. But there is an error message called `/bin/sh: 1: mysql: not found` and error code is `127`. I appreciate your help to understand what this error mean and what I need to do? Does it telling that my `Raspberry Pi 4` is missing something, so it fails to connect to the remote `MySql` through `JavaScript`?

Update:

1. Based on @Mark Setchell suggestion below:
   I have installed the `MySql` on the `RPi` by referring https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-mysql/ The code is `sudo apt install mariadb-server`

[image]

2. @Mark Setchell suggestions: Here is the terminal response

```js
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ /usr/bin/mysql -u fieldArduinoYUN -h aa.bb.cc.dd -p abcdf -e "use field_data; SELECT product FROM product_list WHERE product_id = 123;"
Enter password:    
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'fieldArduinoYUN'@'%' to database 'abcdf'
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Comment: It means you are running a `bash` script which you don't appear to have shown us and it doesn't have its PATH set correctly so it can't find the `mysql` program you tried to run.

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell I appreciate for helping me. As I mentioned in my above, here is the complete script at another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74994968/connect-raspberry-pi-4-to-a-remote-mysql-database-located-on-a-server. Can you please explain in detail what is the PATH here that I did not set correctly? Thanks

Comment: You did `shell.exec(command)` but we can't see `command`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell The command is just above this `shell.exec(command)`. That is, `var command = 'mysql -u '+this.user+' -h '+this.host+' -p'+this.password+' -e "'+sql+'"';` This translates to the command `"command = 'mysql -u this.user -h this.host -p this.password -e sql """`

Comment: Ok, in your Terminal, type `which mysql` and it will tell you where your `mysql` command is installed. Use that full path in your code in place of `mysql`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I just updated my question with a screenshot. I just got an empty response both at the root and home directory.

Comment: Have you installed `mysql` client? If so, how?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am just new to this. What I understand from your question is, do I have to install a MySql client on the `Raspberry Pi 4`? Then only I can connect this `RPi 4` with a `remote MySql` database located on a different server? I am checking my notes (I am noting down all the modules that I installed) and I don't think I installed `MySql client`. But question is, how come same `RPi 4` makes successful connection with `remote MySql` when queried through `python script`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell After doing some search here, some answers pointed towards which shell is being used. Don't know If I worded it correctly here. They suggested this `ls -l \`which sh\`` and I got the following response: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jan  6 16:25 /usr/bin/sh -> dash`.

Comment: Just because Python has a library that can talk to MySQL on another server that doesn't mean there is a program called `mysql` that you can run from a Terminal or call from a `bash` script. So you will need to install the client too.

Comment: If you want to run `mysql ...` in a `bash/dash` shell from Javascript, you must first be able to run that same command from your Terminal.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have update my question with screenshot. Now I have installed `mysql` and I ran `which mysql` and got the response `/usr/bin/mysql`. Now I ran the `javascript` again, but  getting same error. Also, I did not quite understand your comment on running `mysql ..` in a `bash/dash`. Can you please elaborate? Thanks

Comment: You need to be able to run a simple command starting `/usr/bin/mysql -u ... -p ... -h ... -e SOMETHINGSIMPLE` in your Terminal. When that works, replace `mysql` in your `command` with `/usr/bin/mysql`

Comment: Write the password **directly** after `-p` without a space between.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I really appreciate your suggestion. This time I didn't get a `null` error but something new. As you suggested, I ran the command in the terminal. and got the provided terminal response to the above question. Please have a look.

Comment: I want to share here some information here that might help why I am getting `no Access` error. This `RPi 4` is sitting in my office and there is another `Arduino YUN` in our office building elsewhere but connected to the same network. This `Arduino YUN` is also querying the same `MySql` with same credentials as in the above I have used for `RPi`. So, two devices (`Arduino YUN` and `Raspberry PI 4`) querying the remote MySql with same credentials (same user name and password) is allowed? or Do I have to create a new user and password for this `RPi`? Thanks

Comment: @MarkSetchell Hip Hip Hurray! Worked. Fantastic. Yes, I just removed the space between `-p` and password. This worked like fantastic. You are genious. I don't know how to thank you. I have been trying to get this work for past one week. You are truely genious but I have to command your patience. Really hatsoff. Thank you very much.

Comment: Cool  Good luck with your project!

Comment: @MarkSetchell Can you please write the answer and I will accept it. Because, this is important question and not many people know and there are no resources. All my google search for past week only yielded results on how to make/access/install MySql on Raspberry pi but not on how to connect a Raspberry Pi with a remote MySql.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Also, I am curious, deleting space between `-p` and password is it a standard or only for the Raspberry pi? I am puzzled how this small difference is making the big difference.

Comment: Bedtime here  I'll do it tomorrow.

Comment: No issues. I really appreciate for sparing and spending time, during those late hours at your end, to help me solve the problem. I look forward to your answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarising the exchanges from the comments, there were the following issues and solutions.

---

The following error means that the shell (`bash`/`dash`/`ash` etc) was unable to find the `mysql` command:

```
/bin/sh: 1: mysql: not found
```

This normally results from the `PATH` variable not being set to tell the shell where `mysql` is located in the filesystem.

It transpired that, in this case, the reason was that the `mysql` client was not installed. OP had thought that installing a Python module would provide a  command-line **MySQL** client too.

The solution was to install the **MYSQL** client tools.

---

The second issue was that the password for the `mysql` client tool wasn't being provided correctly which resulted in:

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied
```

This can be solved by providing the password  **immediately** following the `-p` option and ***without a space*** like this:

```
/usr/bin/mysql -u USER -h aa.bb.cc.dd -pPASSWORD -e "SOMECOMMAND"
```

Comment: This is a gem of a solution for the week-long effort I had put into solving this issue. I appreciate your patience and excellent solution. I cannot thank you enough.